# Set encrypt to true on Sequelize-cli migrate for MSSQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm trying to run sequelize-cli, specifically `npx sequelize db:migrate`.

I've created a config file in `config/config.js` which looks like this (obviously with correct credentials):

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: "USER",
    password: "PASSWORD",
    database: "DB_NAME",
    host: "HOST.net",
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectOptions: {
      encrypt: "true" // bool - true - doesn't work either
    }
  }
};
```

However I'm receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: Server requires encryption, set 'encrypt' config option to true.
```

As you can see from my config I believe I have set encrypt to true. This is my understanding of how to set this option from [the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/migrations.html).

How can I successfully set `encrypt` to true?

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3240 this issue also leads me to believe what I have above is correct. Though it isn't working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should fix the issue,

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: "USER",
    password: "PASSWORD",
    database: "DB_NAME",
    host: "HOST.net",
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectOptions: { 
      options: {
        encrypt: true
      }
    }
  } 
};
```

Comment: Well, are you trying to do something like this?


`var sequelize = new Sequelize('my - connection - string', {
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectOptions: {
    encrypt: true
  }
});`

Comment: Yes, though doing that does not work either. Same error.

Comment: Okay, I hope this would work,
`module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: "USER",
    password: "PASSWORD",
    database: "DB_NAME",
    host: "HOST.net",
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectOptions: {
      options: {
        encrypt: true
      }
    }
  }
};`

Comment: Oh wow, that worked - that seems to be a poor implementation/documentation. Thanks if you update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Updated. And yes, they do have bad documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your ***config.js***

```
module.exports = {
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: this should work aswell